# Angular material 2 tooltip issue

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I simply added tooltip to a div like so :

```
<div  matTooltip="yeayh">
</div>
```

And added the 2 module below to the parent module :

```
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatTooltipModule,
```

The toolTip is displayed with no issue but I get this in the browser console :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (TooltipComponent.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11087)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10463)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10641)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10464)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10662)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10459)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
```

Comment: It seems like some js is running before the dom is loaded. Can you trace the error?

Comment: This is all I get from the console, the issue seems to come from `TooltipComponent` which is the material component for tooltip. Here I have no idea how to resolve that or at least find where the issue is comming from precisely

Comment: You can maybe use chrome debugger in order to trace it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change "@angular/cdk" version (e.g. "^6.0.0")

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/baprrvoeynl?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts - here the same problem. So when I changed 'cdk' version the problem is gone

Comment: I was using cdk version : 6.4.5

Answer (score 0):

try to update angular material to the new version 7.2.1
see instruction [angulat material install](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

then add to the file "\src\styles.css" the CSS

@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

Answer (score 0):

> TooltipComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')**
>     at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (TooltipComponent.html:1:51)
>     at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:23936:1)

This can be solved by keeping "@angular/cdk": & "@angular/material": version same.

The versions must be as [image: below]: